# "mit... zu bringen"

Tags: preposition, sentence-structure, separable-verb

I came across this clause in reading an academic text on Buddhism (1927):

> ...die heiligen Bücher von Indien mit heim nach China zu bringen.

I get the meaning of it, 'to bring the holy books with [them] from India back home to China', but I don't quite understand the syntax of *mit* here. Is *mit* a separable prefix, from *mitbringen*? Or is it modifying something else? What's the syntax here governing the placement of verb and adverbs here?

Comment: 1) Is mit a separable prefix, from mitbringen?  yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Mit" is used as an adverb here, meaning "together with something/someone", where someone/something is implicit. Here, the implicit "someone" is probably the subject her-/himself, but it could also be other stuff the person is bringing home to China, dependent on context outside of this fragment.

For more on "mit" as an adverb, see: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/mit_neben_damit

The verb "mitbringen" would have the same meaning, but it would not be separated here. "Mitbringen" would be used like this:

> ...die heiligen Bücher von Indien heim nach China **mitzubringen**.

Comment: That is a sophisticated analysis! Could you elaborate why _mitbringen_ would not be separated here?

Comment: Well, we generally just don't do that with separable verbs for a "zu" infinitive, do we? Put objects or adverbials between parts of the verb? <strike>"Ich mag es, an vor der Kasse zu stehen"? "Ich bin gewohnt, meinen Freunden bei in schweren Zeiten zu stehen"?</strike> I might be missing something, but I think this is quite general with "zu" infinitives.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Der Klarheit halber: die beiden Beispiele in meinem Kommentar waren Beispiele, wie man es **nicht** sagt. Das strike-Tag scheint nur in Antworten, aber nicht in Kommentaren zu funktionieren. Und zu taggen haben ich auch vergessen...

Comment: Great! Thanks for the explanation! +1 for this. I think, your comment could well be incorporated in the answer, but that's of course your decision. :)

Answer (score 1):

> … die heiligen Bücher von Indien *mit* heim nach China *zu bringen*.

The problem with this snippet is the somewhat strange word order. I hesitate to call it wrong, but it makes understanding the syntax more difficult. Look at this more comprehensible word order:

> … die heiligen Bücher von Indien heim nach China *mitzubringen*.

Now, you can see immediately that your idea is correct: we are dealing here with the separable verb [*mitbringen*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/mitbringen) in the infinitive form with *zu*. It is composed of the separable prefix [*mit-*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/mit-) and the particle verb [*bringen*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/bringen); the conjunction [*zu*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/zu#%C3%9Cbersetzungen_4) is placed in-between.

In the original snippet, where the prefix is separated and placed away from the rest, the conjunction is separated, too:

> *mit … zu bringen*.

Comment: But why assume a particle verb *mitbringen* with the given order? 1) Other particles cannot be split from the verb in this fashion: **auf nach China zu brechen*, **aus nach China zu wandern*. 2) The second order, with *mitzubringen*, is less natural (certainly less common) than the first. 3) Adverbial *mit* has to be assumed anyway for cases in which *mit* combines with a particle verb: *Das war schwer mit anzusehen. Ich würde gern mit auswandern.*

Answer (score 1):

Please, for your next question: Always post **WHOLE** sentences, not fragments. Grammar is the science of joining words together to form sentences, not fragments!

Your fragment seams to be a subordinate clause. Maybe the full sentence was something like this:

> Lisas Aufgabe war, **die heiligen Bücher von Indien mit heim nach China zu bringen.**
> Lisa's task was **to bring the holy books along from India home to China.**

Without »heim nach China« (*home to China*) it would be this sentence:

> Lisas Aufgabe war, die heiligen Bücher von Indien **mitzubringen.**
> Lisa's task was to **bring** the holy books **along** from India.

The same verb in a main clause:

> Lisa **bringt** die heiligen Bücher von Indien **mit.**
> Lisa **brings along** the holy books from India.

Futur I (becasue in this tense, the verb is used in its infinite form:

> Lisa wird die heiligen Bücher von Indien **mitbringen.**
> Lisa will **bring along** the holy books from India.

---

The German verb [etwas mitbringen](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/mitbringen) means

- to bring something along
- to bring something with one

The prefix *mit-* always means, that something happens together with something else (German preposition *mit = with*). So, *mitbringen* means, that Lisa travels from India to China, and together with (mit) this movement she brings something from India to China.

You could also use just *bringen = to bring,* but there is a very subtile difference:

> 1. Tom wird die Pizza zur Party bringen.
> 2. Tom wird die Pizza zur Party mitbringen.

Both sentences mean *"Tom will bring the pizza to the party".* But in #1 it is very likely, that Tom is just the pizza delivery boy. He rings, delivers the pizza and then drives back to where he came from. In sentence #2 it is very clear, that Tom is one of the guests. He is coming because he wants to attend the party. Bringing the pizza is just the subplot.

The same is true for the person who brings the books from India to China. If you use *bringen* (without mit-) then the most likely meaning is, that this person acts like the pizza boy: The purpose of the travel is to deliver the book. When this is done, the person travels home to India.

But when you use *mitbringen,* then you say, that the person is traveling to China anyway, for some other reason. And because this person is by accident on the way to China, and the books needs to be brought there, is is a good idea, that this person brings them. But the main reason for the journey is not bringing the books, but something else.

---

You also already have noticed, that *mitbringen* is a separable verb. They split and merge depending on the grammatical context:

- Futur I

  > Er wird etwas **mitbringen.**
- Präsens

  > Er **bringt** etwas **mit.**
- Perfekt (here you need the participle)

  > Er hat etwas **mitgebracht.**
- »Erweiterter Infinitiv« or »Infinitiv mit "zu"«

  > Er beschließt, etwas **mitzubringen.**

So, *mitzubringen* should be written as one word. But only becasue it is a separable verb. *Bringen* is not separable, so when you use just *bringen* (without "mit"), the correct version is

> Er beschließt, etwas **zu bringen.**

And now comes the trick:

You can squeeze other parts of speech between the parts of a separable verb. But when you do so, you obviously are no longer able to write the parts together as one word. And then, you have to separate al three parts:

> ... mitzubringen → ... mit ... zu bringen

> 1. Lisas Aufgabe war, die heiligen Bücher von Indien **mitzubringen.**
> 2. Lisas Aufgabe war, die heiligen Bücher von Indien *heim nach China* **mitzubringen.**
> 3. Lisas Aufgabe war, die heiligen Bücher von Indien **mit** *heim nach China* **zu bringen.**

Versions 2 and 3 are both correct. It is just a matter of personal flavor which of them you prefer.

Comment: I think your first sentence would fit better as a comment to the question. I don't know if you are aware of this, but some people on the internet consider writing all caps as screaming (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Association_with_shouting). Also, did you notice that hwaeom is new to german.SE? :)

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Yes, I am aware of both facts. But are you aware, that many other people (including me) consider writing all caps just as emphasis?