# uns Eimer mit reingestellt

Tags: grammaticality, vocabulary

What does

> Wir haben zum Beispiel, wenn wir geduscht haben, uns Eimer mit reingestellt und haben die dann im Garten verteilt.

mean?

The "uns Eimer mit reingestellt" part seems very weird to me.

Source: https://www.tagesschau.de/ausland/usa-kalifornien-duerre-101.html

Comment: Regarding "mit" as an adverb, see for example https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/61943/mit-zu-bringen

Answer (score 3):

It means you have put the bucket in with you in the shower.

Reinstellen is the short form of hereinstellen, meaning to put something into something (into a standing position). Here: to put the bucket into the shower. Compare this to reinlegen and reinsetzen (a lying or sitting position respectively).

The base form would be *jemandem etwas mit reinstellen*, where jemanden is the dative object.